# Flask view decorators and streamed content

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

Flask allows users to create [custom endpoint decorators](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/viewdecorators/), and also [to stream responses](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/streaming/) (basically by returning a generator in a [flask.Response](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Response)).

I would like to make the two concepts work together. Here is a decorator that initializes and closes a context before and after a request is processed. (In real life, it does database connection related stuff):

```
def mydecorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Start context")
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("End context")
        return result
    return decorated_function
```

And now here are two endpoints, the first one is a regular one, and the second one is a streamed one.

```
@app.route("/regular")
@mydecorator
def regular_endpoint():
    print("start normal")
    random_function_that_need_the_decorator_context()
    print("end normal")
    return render_template("whatever.html")
# prints: start context, start normal, end normal, end context

@app.route("/streamed")
@mydecorator
def streamed_endpoint():
    def mygenerator():
        print("start generator")
        random_function_that_need_the_decorator_context()
        for _ in range(1000):
            yield "something"
        print("end generator")

    return Response(mygenerator())
# prints: start context, end context, start generator, end generator
```

The regular endpoint works as expected, but the streamed endpoint fails because the inner generator function needs the decorator context, but the decorator context is closed by the time the generator function is executed.

Is there a way to keep the decorator context opened by the time the generator is executed?
There is a [stream_with_context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.stream_with_context) function in flask, but it seems to only provide the flask request context. Playing with [after_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) does not give better results as the function is called before the generator is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Flask will automatically delete the request context once a response is started on the server. This is mainly to prevent memory leaks. Therefore you have to explicitly tell it to keep it. You can do this with "stream_with_context":

```
from flask import stream_with_context

@app.route("/streamed")
@mydecorator
def streamed_endpoint():
    def mygenerator():
       print("start generator")
       random_function_that_need_the_decorator_context()
       for _ in range(1000):
          yield "something"
       print("end generator")

    return Response(stream_with_context(mygenerator()))
```

Tested and working in `Flask==1.1.1`

More info can be found [here](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/flask.stream_with_context.html)